# set timeout for several objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following code for multiple flyers that when clicked will display a help text overlay that goes away after 4 seconds. I can get it to show the help text but the timeout doesnt work.

```
$(".flyercontainer").click(function(){
  $(this).children('.flyerHelp').css('opacity',0.8);
  setTimeout(function(){
      $(this).children('.flyerHelp').css('opacity',0);
  },4000);
})
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `this` in your `setTimeOut()`'s callback is not what you think it is (it points to the global object, `window`).

```
$(".flyercontainer").click(function(){
  var children = $(this).children('.flyerHelp');
  children.css('opacity',0.8);
  setTimeout(function(){
      children.css('opacity',0);
  },4000);
});
```

Comment: I downvoted because your original post wasn't an answer, all you wrote was "`this` isn't what you think it is in your function" without explaining what it is or how to fix it. I changed my vote now that you edited your post to show a good fix for it.

Comment: @user1: It was still an answer, and the advice I gave was correct, was it not?

Comment: You didn't give any advice before. Now that you have you have an upvote from me. IMO it deserved a downvote before and now it deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, `this` refers to the `window` object when used in the scope of the callback function for the `window.setTimeout()` method. You can get around this by setting a variable equal to `this` in the scope of the `click` handler for `.flyercontainer`, but outside of your call to `setTimeout()`.

Alternatively, you can chain jQuery's `delay()` method between two zero-duration animations for the opacity of the object to achieve the same effect. (Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/V2ZYy/)